# Firewall Rule with Powershell through Python

Tags: python, powershell, firewall

So I am trying to make a script that blocks a specific IP on my firewall.

I found that the Powershell command is:

```
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Name of Scope" -Direction Outbound –LocalPort Any -Protocol TCP -Action Block -RemoteAddress 11.11.11.11/32
```

Now I'm not sure if that shell command is good or not but It's just what I found.

Now to execute a powershell command through python I read that I need to use either `os.system()` or `subprocess.Popen`.

Would anyone be kind enough to tell me how to perform this task please since what I tried didn't work.

Comment: As aside, the `–` for parameter `LocalPort` looks like an [EM DASH](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_punctuation.asp). Replace that by a normal dash `-`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run windows-powershell commands from python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54338990/how-to-run-windows-powershell-commands-from-python)